# Jquery css селекторы

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="_sameclass">Text</td>
    <td style="display: none;"></td>
    <td></td>                             //put data here
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="_sameclass">OtherText</td>
    <td style = "display: none;"></td>
    <td></td>                             //different data here
</tr>
```

Как написать селектор под это? Нужно выбирать 3 по счёту `<td></td>` в каждом `<tr>`. При условии что в каждый `<td>` будут вноситься уникальные данные, поэтому их нужно разделить. И нельзя использовать `empty` селектор, потому что он после заполнения работать не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прям всегда только третий, и никогда другой, то
`$("tr td:nth-child(3)")`

Псевдокласс `:nth-child` используется для добавления стиля к элементам на основе нумерации в дереве элементов.

Синтаксис:
`элемент:nth-child(odd | even | <число> | <выражение>) {...}`